# SwiftUI - Accessing a property of a generic observed class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI.

I have a view declared like this:

```
struct MyScrollView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var model:MyModel

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      HStack {
        ForEach(model.items!, id: \.self) { title in
          Text(title)
        }
      }
    }
```

Now I want to create a new kind of scrollView, that inherits all this defined for `MyScrollView`. In fact I would love to create an "instance" of `MyScrollView` and extend its methods and properties.

The problem is that structs cannot be instanced.

If `MyScrollView` was a class what I would like is this:

```
class MySuperScrollView: MyScrollView {
  var anotherProperty:Bool

  func anotherFunction() -> Bool {
     return anotherProperty
  }
}
```

^ this in terms of struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inherit struct views, but you can aggregate one into another, like

```
struct MySuperScrollView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: MyModel
  var anotherProperty:Bool

  func anotherFunction() -> Bool {
     return anotherProperty
  }

  var body: some View {
     // ... other elements around

     MyScrollView(model: self.model)

     // ... other elements around
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the properties and functions of MyScrollView? How do I acess them?

Comment: You should not. In SwiftUI data flow between views goes either via view model, or via binding, or via modifiers. Views are structs, ie. values.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is not the way to create reusable SwiftUI views that you can extend with extra properties.

Instead of using inheritance, you should use composition, which means that you break up your views into small reusable components and then add these views to the body of your other view to compose a more complex view.

However, without seeing exactly what changes you want to achieve, I cannot give you an exact code example.